# How to amplify signal enough to make a Langevin transducer vibrate?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, modulation, piezo, transducer

I'm a little out of my zone of mechanical engineering here, so I'll need your help.

Up to date, I got the right frequency (40 kHz modulated for a 200 Hz low frequency) coming out of my function generator.

I need to transform this function into a mechanical vibration, so I bought myself a Langevin transducer (piezo.)

How do I generate enough power (60W) to make this piezo (100ohm at 40kHz) vibrate?

We thought of #1 - amplifier (not working with this frequency and capacity) or #2 - DC-DC- converter to be able to be able to take impedance variation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to drive it is with a piezo driver that automatically generates the correct frequency.

Since it sounds like you need something other than simply "buzz,"  you need an amplifier to make a powerful enough signal to drive the piezo element.  An audio amplifier won't work as it won't have the bandwidth and won't be built to work with a 100ohm capacitive load.

You'll need an amplifier designed for the use you will be putting it to.  You could purchase such an amplifier, possibly from the same supplier who sold you the transducer.

Alternatively, you could build your own, [like this person did.](http://www.imajeenyus.com/electronics/20110514_power_ultrasonic_driver/index.shtml)

That site provides a complete schematic of an oscillator and a driver:

[image]

The circled section is the piezo driver.  Note that it operates directly on line voltage - you will need to use an isolation transformer to keep it from killing you.

---

A DC-DC converter wouldn't help.  You need an AC signal to drive the transducer, and a DC-DC converter provides DC only at the output.