# I need to create a mechanical vibration of 40 kHz. What would you suggest?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, piezo, vibration

For research purposes, I need to make a vibration of 40 kHz modulated at 200 Hz. I have a DDS signal generator that can output this specific signal.

I tried to amplify this signal, but I'm nowhere close to being able to drive my piezo transducer. I'm looking for something like a piezo transducer but needing way less than 60 W.

If anyone has a suggestion and a way of creating this vibration I'd be thankful.

Also I'm a little low budget here.

Comment: Have you tried googling piezo driver circuits? Or maybe even "ultrasonic distance detector schematic" for some interface ideas?

Comment: I've been on it for two weeks.. Because of my specific frequency, generic piezo's driver are not my solution. Right now my set up is "DDS generator --> audio amp --> piezo transducer"

Comment: You need to add this detail into your question and explain why this is so.

Comment: Most (decent) audio amplifiers are designed to filter/reject frequencies above about 20 kHz (above the audible range).

Comment: Your earlier question seems very similar to the one above: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/652382/how-to-amplify-signal-enough-to-make-a-langevin-transducer-vibrate

Comment: @qc_engineering - Depends on what kind of "vibration" you want to generate and what you want to couple it into. **What kind of vibration:** What amplitude and which directions? Only a single axis, or multiple? What waveform of vibration? Only sinusodial or something more fancy?
If multiple axis: What is the relative function between the axis? Is it a circular interpolation? Or is it trivial? **What do you want to couple too:** Do you want to couple it into a solide fixture like something made out of metall? Or a liquid like water? Or a gas environment?

Comment: Ultrasonic humidifiers run around 800 kHz-1.7 MHz . Plenty of power, but would the high frequency be suitable?